# Animated not working when i convert Gif to webp in PHP

Tags: php, gd, imagick, animated-gif, webp

I convert animated gif to webp but the webp picture is not animated.

Did I miss a step?
I don't find in the documentation.

my code:

```
//GD
$image = imagecreatefromgif("./mypics.gif");
imagepalettetotruecolor($image);
imagewebp($image, "./image.webp");

//Imagick
$img = new \Imagick("./mypics.gif");
$img->stripImage();
$img->setImageFormat("webp");
$img->setImageAlphaChannel(\imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_ACTIVATE);
$img->setBackgroundColor(new \ImagickPixel('transparent'));
$img->writeImage("./image.webp");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[php-vips](https://github.com/libvips/php-vips) supports animated web. For example:

```php
// n=-1 means load all pages
// sequential access means decode pixels on demand
$image = Vips\Image::newFromFile('something.gif', [
    'n' => -1,
    'access' => 'sequential'
]); 
$image->writeToFile('something.webp');
```

Answer (score 2):

GD does not support animated WebP.
Imagemagick does, but only since relatively recent version 7.0.8-68 and if compiled with libwebp.

You either need to install latest imagemagick with webp support, or use some other external tool, like [gif2webp](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/docs/gif2webp).

Comment: I installed imagemagick 7.0.10-24 and the webp are animated.
For the moment I'm executing a command with the exec() function from PHP, because the php-imagick package uses a version that doesn't support animated webp.